# Message: no such element: Unable to locate element (Python, Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have list_of_links which is containing 2 videos that are having creators with less the 500 subscribers and one video that is having a huge number of subscribers. My task in here is to get only those creators that are having less then 500 subscribers I tried it like this, but it is giving me an error with this [traceback](/questions/tagged/traceback)

```
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_18264\3954802536.py in <module>
      5     driver.get(link)
      6     x_path_for_followers = '//*[@id="owner-sub-count"]'
----> 7     followers = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value=x_path_for_followers)
      8     nFollowers = getNumberOfFolowers(followers) # a duncion to parse from the text here to number
      9     if nFollowers > 500:
```

This is what I tried:

```
list_of_links = ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXUW-BfPNx8', 'https://www.youtube.com/watchv=b9s_xrycvGA', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9TUPpGqYTo']

creators = set()
for link in list_of_links:
    driver.get(link)
    x_path_for_followers = '//*[@id="owner-sub-count"]'
    followers = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value=x_path_for_followers)
    nFollowers = getNumberOfFolowers(followers) # a duncion to parse from the text here to number
    if nFollowers > 500:
        continue
    x_path_for_creator = '//*[@id="text"]/a'
    creator = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value=x_path_for_creator)
    href = creator.get_attribute("href")
    creators.append(href)
```

I want to get these 2 creators (they are creators of 2 first videos and they have less then 500 suscribers):  **@translationalbiology5464, @imjustslightlybetter**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error clearly indicates, it's unable to find the element by the given XPath.

You can try this way:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

def getNumberOfFolowers(text):
    text = text.replace(' subscribers', '')
    if 'K' in text:
        num = float(text.replace('K', ''))*1000
    elif 'M' in text:
        num = float(text.replace('M', '')) * 1000000
    else:
        num = text
    return int(num)

list_of_links = ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBk60Pv_BMo', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cnwt5emWaOg', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBXtdBnEUvo', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZ8uXq5VG2w', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03c8M6LZR_k']

creators = set()
for link in list_of_links:
    driver.get(link)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[id="owner"]')))
    followers = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[id="owner"]').text.split('\n')[1]
    nFollowers = getNumberOfFolowers(followers)
    if nFollowers > 500:
        continue
    creator = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="text"]/a').get_attribute('href')
    creator_id = creator.replace('https://www.youtube.com/', '')
    creators.add(creator_id)

print(creators)
```

creators:

```
{'@ajeet214_', '@DeltaFilmsStudio'}
```

Comment: It works if I had small number of videos, but however it shows this error when it tries on for example 400 link videos.                                                                                                                         
` ---> 62     WebDriverWait(driver, [1]
     85             if time.monotonic() > end_time:
     86                 break
---> 87         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

`

Comment: And i forgot to ask one more question, what if someone had "1 subscriber", it's not the same pattern as with " subscribers"? :/

Comment: for "1 subscriber", simply add one more elif condition in getNumberOfFolowers function and replace " subscriber" with "".

Comment: and about your first question, I think it's because as you open more videos in a very short span, the page loads very slowly and that's why you get TimeoutException, You can try increasing the maximum wait time,  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[id="owner"]'))) and see if it works

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast, I tried with 20, even bigger numbers, but  it didn't work, is there any alternative solution for that? Here is the link for whole code :)   [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75973607/timeoutexceptionmessage-screen-stacktrace-python-selenium)

Comment: sometimes it shows me this error as well : invalid literal for int() with base 10:,, but not always, I'm not sure due to what

Comment: the error, invalid literal for int() with base 10. it may be because sometimes the web element of the "subscribers" might not load properly and it returns an empty string or something and in such case the  "getNumberOfFolowers" function, int(" ") would result in error "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10"

Comment: And I can not think of any way to fix the TimeoutException error, as it occurs because Google detects unusual traffic(100s of requests) in a very short time from the same IP or device.

Comment: Understood, is there any limit i need to respect?