# TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) Python, Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I scraped video links off of youtube based on the given keyword, and I want to get the list of names of creators with only less then 500 subscribers, on small lists it works, but when i have lists that contain for example 400 subscribers it doesnt work, it gives me this error:

```
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10072\1432590254.py in <module>
     61 for link in list_of_links:
     62     driver.get(link)
---> 63     WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[id="owner"]')))
     64     followers = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[id="owner"]').text.split('\n')[1]
     65     nFollowers = getNumberOfFolowers(followers)

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     85             if time.monotonic() > end_time:
     86                 break
---> 87         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     88 
     89     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
```

Here is the code, i expected to get the list of creators that have less then 500 subscribers

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)


#transforming text into numbers
def getNumberOfFolowers(text):
    text = text.replace(' subscribers', '')
        
    if 'K' in text:
        num = float(text.replace('K', ''))*1000
    elif 'M' in text:
        num = float(text.replace('M', '')) * 1000000
    else:
        num = text
    return int(num)

#function for scraping
search_word = input("Enter the search keyword: ")
url = f"https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={search_word}"


driver.get(url)
# scroll the page until it ends
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
while True:
    # Scroll to the bottom of page
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);", last_height)
    # Wait for new videos to show up
    time.sleep(1)
    # Calculate new document height and compare it with last height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

time.sleep(3)
videos = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'ytd-video-renderer')
print(f"total videos: {len(videos)}")

list_of_links = []
for video in videos:
    link = video.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'h3').find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').get_attribute('href')
    list_of_links.append(link)

#clicking on each video code


creators = set()
for link in list_of_links:
    driver.get(link)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[id="owner"]')))
    followers = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[id="owner"]').text.split('\n')[1]
    nFollowers = getNumberOfFolowers(followers)
    if nFollowers > 500:
        continue
    creator = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="text"]/a').get_attribute('href')
    creator_id = creator.replace('https://www.youtube.com/', '')
    creators.add(creator_id)

print(creators)
    


    

# ser manual input
```